# How to use top level Async await released in v8 typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await

I'm trying hard to understand what exactly this new feature (top level async await) means [from v8 features list](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-8/)

When I try to run in vanila JS the results seems quite same to me here's what I try to do in vanilla js.

```js
(() => {
  let test1 = async() =>
    async() => {
      return 'true';
    };

  (async() => {
    let result = await test1();
    result = await result();
    console.log('r', result)
  })();

})()
```

I want to know what exactly this feature means and how to use it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is [v8's document](https://v8.dev/features/top-level-await). To me it is pretty self descriptive and a very handy feature for me personally.

Previously, you couldn't just write `await someAsyncFunction()` out of no where because for **await**ing a function you must call the `await` inside an `async` function.

**Example:**

**main.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');
const unlink = util.promisify(fs.unlink); // promisify unlink function
await unlink('file_path'); // delete file
```

The above code would not work. The last line would give you an error. So, what we did previously is something like this:

```
async function main() {
    const fs = require('fs');
    const util = require('util');
    const unlink = util.promisify(fs.unlink); // promisify unlink function
    await unlink('file_path'); // delete file
}
main();
```

But, now you don't **(!)** have to do this. The first code would work.

**THIS ANSWER IS BASED ON MY UNDERSTANDING**

Answer (score 1):

Top level async await allows you to await Promises returned by async functions at the top level of a module, without having to declare a separate async function. Most importantly, you can now conveniently `export` values returned by async functions.

For example, without this feature, you need to create a separate async function (the usual "main" async function), or use `Promise.then` in order to do something with the returned value at the top-level, and cannot simply export the returned value.

```js
  let test = async () => 'true';

  test().then(result => console.log('r', result));

  // or even more verbose
  (async () => {
    console.log(await test());
  })();

  // This exports a Promise, not the returned value, "true".
  export let result = test();

  // This throws an Error because export should be at the top-level.
  (async () => {
    export let result = await test();
  })();
```

But with this new feature, you can simply do:

```js
  let test = async () => 'true';
  export let result = await test();
  console.log(result);
```

This feature is especially useful when you want to export a value that **has to be obtained asynchronously**; for example, a value you get from network at run-time, or a module like a big encryption suite that is large and loads slowly and asynchronously.